# Start SQL Server only when SSMS is started

Tags: sql-server, powershell, cmd, scripting, ssms

I've recently installed **SQL Server 2019** and is eating a good 3 GB or RAM at startup.

I just use it at home for personal use so I've turned it off.

I would like to know if there is a way to wite a script in `PowerShell` or `CMD` that:

1. Starts `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)` when I fire up SSMS
2. Stop `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)` when I close SSMS

Comment: Since you already tagged [tag:scripting] - just create a script to start SQL server and SSMS and pin that to Start Menu or Task Ba. The hard part would be rather a way to stop SQL server when you exit SSMS.

Comment: Also, consider setting SQL Server's [max server memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options?view=sql-server-ver15) to a reasonable limit.

Comment: @vonPryz, I need full force when I work, so this is not an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself:

```
# Execute this script as Administrator
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }

# Start all SQL* Services
Get-Service | where {$_.Name -like "SQL*"} |  Start-Service

# Start SSMS and wait till is closed
Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe" -NoNewWindow -Wait

# Stop all SQL* Services
Get-Service | where {$_.Name -like "SQL*"} |  Stop-Service
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create script which will start/stop the server (e.g. batch file or PowerShell) and then run SSMS.exe.

You can also start/stop SQL server engine in:

**Command Prompt**

```
net start "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)"
net stop "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)"
```

**PowerShell**

```
# Get a reference to the ManagedComputer class.
CD SQLSERVER:\SQL\computername
$Wmi = (get-item .).ManagedComputer

$DfltInstance = $Wmi.Services['MSSQLSERVER']

# Display the state of the service.
$DfltInstance

# Start the service.
$DfltInstance.Start();

# Wait until the service has time to start.
# Refresh the cache.  
$DfltInstance.Refresh();

# Display the state of the service.
$DfltInstance

# Stop the service.
$DfltInstance.Stop();

# Wait until the service has time to stop.
# Refresh the cache.
$DfltInstance.Refresh();

# Display the state of the service.
$DfltInstance
```

More details on [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/start-stop-pause-resume-restart-sql-server-services?view=sql-server-ver15#ssmsde).

Answer (score 0):

How about this script? It will wait until SSMS exits, then stop SQL Server. Of course, your path the the SSMS executable might be different than mine.

```
net start "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)"
START /WAIT "" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft SQL Server Tools 17\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17.lnk"
net stop "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)"
```